# Expose internal application data/variables to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Given a Kubernetes pod with a yaml as shown below, are there any way to set up the value of the terminationGracePeriodSeconds according to some global/internal variable of the application being executed.

[image]

Otherwise said and more generally, I know that through downward API, data from the infrastructure/kubernetes (IP, host, …) can be exposed to the application. On the other side, are there any method to expose internal application data/variables to the infrastructure i.e. Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of configuration is exactly what tools like [Helm](https://helm.sh) are good for.  You could configure a Helm chart with a value:

```yaml
# charts/my-app/values.yaml

# terminationWait specifies the time to wait for a process to exit
# before forcibly killing the container.
terminationWait: 60
```

And then reference that value in your YAML manifests:

```yaml
# charts/my-app/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ .Values.terminationWait }}
```

More generally it uses the Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language, with a large set of extensions, so it's possible to do almost anything with this setup, though it's easiest and clearest to stick with simple value substitution like what's shown here.

Comment: Say I have in my application (say java or python app running as container) a variable 'terminationWait', I can not see how to link/associate my application variable  'terminationWait' into the helm configuration terminationWait! my question is about exposing an application variable to kubernetes wether thorugh helm or yaml? am I missing smthg? AFAIK, this requires restarting the pod and most likely not availble out of the box in kubernetes?

Comment: Deleting and recreating pods is extremely routine in Kubernetes; `kubectl delete pod` is one of my go-tos if something is misbehaving.  You could look into writing a _controller_ if you have application-level configuration that you need to publish into Kubernetes too, but that's more involved.  In general, beyond basic things like health checks, Kubernetes can't call into your application or extract data from it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a function like kubectl apply, or kubectl patch, to trigger update of manifest file parameters.
so its not just like setting
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: $somevar
and have it updated every time the variable changes.

If change of this value is once per deployment, you can use template tools like Helm, or Knative.

or you can use [operator framework](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk) to implement your own operator for this purpose.